# How to Migrate Thingsboard server to new server/ new PC Thingsboard CE Installation in window

Tags: migration, window, iot, thingsboard

currently I am using Thingsboard community edition 3.4 with the use of postgresql database. I try to migrate the things board data including the devices, rule chain, and dashboard to the new host as the requirement. Both of the servers currently used use the installation in the Window, can I get advice/suggestions on how to migrate the current things board data to the new host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a backup of the entire PostgreSQL database of ThingsBoard and move it to the new server.

example with pg_dump:

```
sudo -Hiu postgres pg_dump thingsboard > thingsboard.sql.bak
```

Comment: is that backup in postgre it will automatically link to the thingsboard? because new server if create new device the token number is different and i think it will not display in the dashboard...

Comment: You have to stop the ThingsBoard service on the new Server, drop the existing thingsboard database (which should be almost empty after fresh installation) & import the backup from your original server. Then restart the TB service again.

Comment: If i use pgadmin4 to make backup and restore the database via restore functions in pgadmin4, is the result would be same also?

Comment: but thank you for great advise, will have a try first

Comment: Yes, this should be also possible to create the backup via pgadmin instead of pg_dump cli tool